# Button with Table won't fire on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table and I'm trying to set up a button to launch a function when clicked but it won't.

```
    <tbody>
        <!-- new row for every file -->
        <tr ng-repeat="file in ReportModel.report track by $index" on-finish-render>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs  btn-success" ng-click="undoCheckOut(file.absoluteUrl)"> 
                    <i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-fw fa-flip-horizontal"></i>
                </button>
                <a ng-href="{{file.absoluteUrl}}">{{file.fileName}}</a>
            </td>
            <td>{{file.fileUrl}}</td>
            <td>{{file.checkedTo}}</td>
            <td>{{file.modified}}</td>
            <td>{{file.createdBy}}</td>
            <td>{{file.version}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Controller function:

```
    $scope.undoCheckOut = function(file){
        console.log('uncheckingout file', file);
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "UndoCheckOut",
            pageUrl: file 
        });

        alert('Discarded checked out for ', file.fileName);
    }
```

The table renders without issue so the controller and view are working.

Comment: when you click the button do you get an error message in your console?

Comment: There's no error and the control console log don't run either.

Comment: on-finish-render might be doing something, otherwise it looks fine.

Comment: hmm, kk I'm take it out and see. EDIT: yup, didn't help. Weird.